# Asp.Net Core signalR is not working if publishing inside virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have developed an application in asp.net core and used signalR. When i publish it in root directory it works fine, but if i publish it inside virtual directory it doesn't work. My signalR hub is always pointing to the root directory.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ... other middleware ...
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
    });
}
```

And i have initialized it in client side like this,

**chat.js**

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection("/chat");
```

After publishing it inside virtual directory(/development/chatapp/source) it points like this,
http://localhost:100/chat?userId=1

But actually it has to point like this, so that it will work
http://localhost:100/development/chatapp/source/chat?userId=1

I have used asp.net core 2.0 and this signalR version(1.0.0-preview1-final).

Someone please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of my friend i have found the root cause for this issue and i fixed it. Actually javascript doesn't know whether the application is hosted in root folder or sub folder(in virtual directory). It always points the root folder.

So when we are initializing it in js like this(new signalR.HubConnection("/chat")), it points the root directory as below,

http://localhost:100/chat?userId=1

Since javascript doesn't aware of IIS hosting, we need to tell the relative path from c#. So i get my application's base path as follows in controller,

```
ViewData["PathBase"] = Request.PathBase.ToString();
```

And if it has some value i just prepend it to '/chat', otherwise i just initialize it as '/chat'.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnection("/development/chatapp/source/chat");
```

This solves my problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Kailash P : With the help of my friend i have found the root ...

OK, thanks for your sharing.

I'm publish the SignalR Chat sample to IIS but NOT WORKS --X

SignalRChat :

Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR
　https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

*With Visual Studio debugging, the sample are works but NOT WORKS publish to IIS.

In page load, the send message button not enabled because there have some errors :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)　　chatHub/negotiate:1
[2019-11-18T06:40:26.977Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Internal Server Error　　Utils.ts:179

--

After add the vitural directory the SignalR Chat sample WORKS :

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

->

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chat1/chatHub").build();

Don't know why there have no any official note about this problem (SignalR publishing).

[NET Core 2.2]
[Visual Studio 2019]